# Tuple unpacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a tuple that looks like this:

`('Elizabeth', 'Peter, Angela, Thomas')`

How could I separate the last value in it so it would look like this:

`('Elizabeth', 'Peter', 'Angela', 'Thomas')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> names = ('Elizabeth', 'Peter, Angela, Thomas')
>>> [y for x in names for y in x.split(', ')]
['Elizabeth', 'Peter', 'Angela', 'Thomas']
```

There's also this way, I prefer the first however:

```
>>> ', '.join(names).split(', ')
['Elizabeth', 'Peter', 'Angela', 'Thomas']
```

Of course you can convert the result to a tuple in the end but it is most likely unnecessary to do so.